# How to echo url and database variable

Tags: php, sql, echo

I have a piece of code used to search a database for videos based on keywords. It then pulls the url from column $url. I then want to echo out a hyperlink to the video by echoing the website link and concatenating on the url variable pulled from the database.

So far I've come up with the following code. I'm new to php so im not sure how to concatenate variables in an echo.

```
    echo "<a href=\"danu6.it.nuigalway.ie/sm4business\">Link</a>";
```

Also when I run this code the link  brings me to http://danu6.it.nuigalway.ie/sm4business/danu6.it.nuigalway.ie/sm4business

Any help or resource that could help me to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll find the PHP manual quite enlightening. Particularly the section on [operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dot to concate constant string with variables:

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$name.'</a>';
```

for security reason you need to take care about propper variable escaping. Check php.net doc for `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`

Comment: Thaks for the helpful advice and docs. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Link</a>";
```

or you can concat the $url value in the string like this:

```
 echo "<a href=\"danu6.it.nuigalway.ie/sm4business/$url\">Link</a>";
```

Hope it helps!